# How can I tell if I have BufferedMessage or BodyWriterMessage, when all I get is Message?

Tags: c#, wcf

I've implemented `IClientMessageInspector` and `IDispatchMessageInspector` for some custom logging-type functionality.  In process of making this all more "pluggable" my implementations of each now call some other code that has a `CanProcess(object)` method.  (There are many different plugins so I need to find one that can process a `Message` object, for example.)

Since both the `MyClientMessageInspector.BeforeSendRequest` and `MyDispatchMessageInspector.AfterReceiveRequest` implementations use the `System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message` class for the message due to the interfaces they implement, I need a *reliable* way to know "which" Message I have - the one on a client, or the one from a server?  Sadly, the underlying classes, `BufferedMessage`, and `BodyWriterMessage`, are both marked internal so I can't use those.

**I've put in a string comparison hack I hate but it works**

Here is my `CanProcess` method called by the DispatchMessageInspector:

```
public bool CanProcess(object testObject)
{
    return (testObject != null)
        && (testObject is System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message)
        && (testObject.GetType().UnderlyingSystemType
    .FullName == "System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessage");
}
```

and here is the same as called by the ClientMessageInspector:

```
public bool CanProcess(object testObject)
{
    return (testObject != null)
        && (testObject is System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message)
        && (testObject.GetType().UnderlyingSystemType
   .FullName == "System.ServiceModel.Channels.BodyWriterMessage");
}
```

Any thoughts?  Is there something in `Message.Properties` that I've overlooked, or another attribute of `Message` to distinguish them?

I utterly hate this string comparison hack.

Comment: I made a few edits to clarify and add code snippets. I have this hack that seems to work but it feels fragile... would really appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MessageHeaders for custom identification.

Here is sample of custom WCF message inspector where I populate headers:

```
public class WCFMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{

    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
    }

    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        //in this sample I use predefined Guid to distinct specific client...
        Guid clientId = new Guid("5DBD6E89-81F2-4786-BC93-2758A8368A5D");
        MessageHeader<Guid> header = new MessageHeader<Guid>((Guid)clientId);
        MessageHeader untyped = header.GetUntypedHeader("Identity", "http://www.MyCustomNamespace.com");
        request.Headers.Add(untyped);
        return null;
    }
}
```

On the recieving end you can read this message header like this:

```
MessageHeaders headers = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders;
try
{
    Guid clientId = headers.GetHeader<Guid>("Identity", "http://www.MyCustomNamespace.com");
    if (clientId == new Guid("5DBD6E89-81F2-4786-BC93-2758A8368A5D")
    {
        //TODO: this is our target client, do your stuff here...
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
}
```

The best practice would be also to put key strings/Guid in separate Library and read values from there.